# Is it possible to render readable (unescaped) json into HTML data-attributes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

We are rendering json into data-attributes in ERB.  Eg:

**location.html.erb**

```
<div data-location="<%= render 'location_json' %>">
```

**location_json.erb**

```
<%= @location.to_json(
      only: [:id, :name, :lat, :lng],
      method: [:display_name]) %>
```

The rendered html looks like:

```
<div data-location="{&quot;id&quot;:16,&quot;lat&quot;:&quot;35.688195&quot;,&quot;lng&quot;:&quot;-82.564652&quot;,&quot;name&quot;:&quot;Mountain&quot;}">
```

But I would like it to be more readable, eg:

`<div data-location='{"id":16, "lat":35.688195, "lng":-82.564652, "name":"Mountain"}'`>

Is there a way to tell ERB or to_json to render with single quotes instead of escaping double quotes?

Is it possible to render readable json into HTML data-attributes.  By readable, I mean with the bare minimum of escaping.

Comment: You'll need some combination of `escape_javascript` and `raw`.

Comment: The problem with using single quotes for the data attribute value is that json doesn't escape single quotes, so this breaks:  <div data-location='{"name":"Brian's Song"}'>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to use unescaped JSON in a data-attribute without breaking the html page.

However, it is possible to use escaped JSON that is more readable than the Rails/ERB default.

By default ERB escapes double quotes which makes JSON particularly hard to read.  Instead

- use single quotes for the html data attribute
- call raw to prevent ERB from using the default escaping on your string
- escape all the html significant chars in your string except double quotes

helper.rb

```
def my_html_escape(s)
  { '&' => '&amp;', '>' => '&gt;', '<' => '&lt;', "'" => '&#39;' }.each do |k,v|
   s = s.gsub(k,v)
  end
  s
end
```

location.html.erb

```
<div data-location='<%= raw my_html_escape(@location.to_json) -%>'>
```

produces

```
<div data-location='{"id":16, "lat":35.688195, "lng":-82.564652, "name":"Mountain"}'>
```

Answer (score 3):

in `location.html.erb`

```
 <div data-location="<%= @location.to_json %>">
```

Reference:
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ERB/Util.html#method-c-json_escape

Answer (score 0):

Any gsub.(/'/, '') will escape quotes too.

You may even create a table and iterate over json's response, putting key in first td and value on the second.  If you have one or two jsons will be nice.  If you have a lot with delimited number of elements, create a line to each one.